# SHA512 Encryption + salted

Tags: c#, hash, passwords

I am working on a C# visual studio windows form application. However, i was stuck halfway during my development.

I am trying to ask the user for his/her password before encrypting it with salted.
How can i encrypted my password text with SHA 512 with salted and decrypted it later on? Is there any advise on how i can do it? Is SHA 512 secure enough as compare to other encryption methods?

Comment: Short answer: **DON'T**, it's too fast. Use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt instead. For example with `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and 1k to 100k iterations.

Comment: This is also password hash question number 9001, please put a little bit of effort into searching.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph Would love to see the code....  And Derek, you should've posted your code so we'd know how far you got.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Answer (score 1):

SHA512 is **NOT** a form of encryption, it is a form of hashing. Hashing is one-way - i.e. it cannot be decrypted. The only way to find a value from a hash is by rainbow tables, which is not an exact science, to say the least.

As such, SHA512 is more secure than an encryption method when it comes to a password, as you are never storing something that can be easily decrypted, merely collided with.

Comment: Rainbow tables are not the relevant attack for salted passwords. With salted passwords the attacker simply guesses password candidates. Also SHA-512 is not appropriate for password hashing.

Comment: Last time I checked, a rainbow table is a collection of hashes and their plaintext values. Last time I checked, SHA-512 was one of the leading contenders in terms of password hashing, quoted by no less than NIST themselves: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/secure_hashing.html .

Comment: Rainbow tables are a pre-calculation based variant of multi-target attacks. Correct salting(globally unique salt) prevents all multi target attacks or at least renders them less efficient than straight up password guessing. And please post a reference for NIST recommending SHA-512 *for password hashing*. It's a good general purpose hash, but password hashing has very different requirements from normal hashes.

Comment: *Recommending* and *not being fit for purpose* are not opposites, and there is a lot of scope in between. NIST advocate the use of algorithms that cannot be tuned for performance on GPUs - i.e. they ban SHA-1, MD4, MD5 and blowfish. They also quite clearly state that, while SHA-2 functions are good, bcrypt is better. Finally, they recommend PBKDF2 merely for key generation. (SP800-132)

Comment: @CodesInChaos PBKDF2 is recommended as an algorithm for *generating a cryptographic key from a password*. bcrypt and scrypt, I can understand using.

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific NIST guidance on password hashing at all. But the requirements for password hashing for storage and deriving a key from a password are very similar, so PBKDF2 is fit for both. So if you like SHA-512, at least use PBKDF2 with SHA-512 and not plain SHA-512.

Comment: I just referenced it to you. Special Publication SP800-132.

Comment: I neither like nor dislike SHA-512, and while I agree that scrypt and bcrypt are better password hash choices I don't think that storing properly salted SHA512 hashes is a significant cause for concern in most applications/instances.

Comment: As usual - three concerns to balance: how much time you can spend hashing, how much processing power you can spend hashing, how much other people want your hashed data (i.e. how long do you want them to spend their time hashing). Also, hashing is only one cog in the machine - Sony proved that pretty damn well last year.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis - Everywhere the same arguments. Do you know that for brute-forcing a whole english dictionary with about 500'000 words you only need about [5 milliseconds](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance)? That is in 2012 for SHA-512 with common hardware. The work for implementing BCrypt and SHA512 is the same, so why not just recommend the better one?

Comment: @CodesInChaos is correct.  Those who are arguing with him should read up on how passwords are cracked when you use functions such as SAH512, SHA1, MD5, SHA256, or anything fast to compute.  A good reference is here: https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/

Comment: @TheGreatContini Actually, NIST does have hash algorithm requirements.  http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-131Ar1.pdf - page 14.  And PBKDF2 is not an algorithm, nor a standard, but simply a function you write to apply iterations to your hashing:  https://shauntm.com/notes/entries/443  While useful,  Sébastien was arguing that Chaos didn't understand that there actually are standards - and Sébastien is correct that what you use will be limited by your hardware and how long you want it to chug & how long you want your adversary to chug, & hashing is just one part.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, SHA512 is not secure enough for password processing.  SHA512 is fast, whereas password processing needs to be slow to prevent brute force searches on passwords in the event that the database is dumped by hackers.  Such events happen often!
2. You do not decrypt it later on.  Instead, when you get the plaintext password from the user, you hash it with the salt that is in the database and compare the result with the encoded hash in the database.  If it matches, then user is authenticated.
3. Information about what's wrong with SHA512/SHA256/SHA1/MD5/anything fast is provided [here](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes), including .Net code that shows how to use a more appropriate function (PBKDF2) for password processing.
4. [Crackstation.net](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) also gives decent education on how to do password processing, but not specific to .Net.  Make sure to especially read the "Making Password Cracking Harder: Slow Hash Functions" to understand why SHA512 is not appropriate.
5. There is a lot of bad advice on password processing in a lot of places.  You should check the security reputations of those people providing advice so you can distinguish the good from the rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

Others say "SHA-512 is not encryption", but neglect to say that you can, and how you can, actually encrypt WITH it. Encryption requires a public key (for encrypting) & a private key (for decryption), if you are using an RSACryptoServiceProvider & asymmetric encryption, as shown below. Since you can create SHA512-based hashed keys, you can encrypt/decrypt against them. For doing the salt, you could potentially look at http://www.obviex.com/samples/EncryptionWithSalt.aspx. I don't go into that, here.

For those that may complain about this answer below & say "use PBKDF2":

1. I have no idea what this is. Don't expect every developer to know, either, and how to implement it as easily as you do.
2. In my work environment we have a separate developer network that is not connected to the internet, so it makes things like 3rd-party libraries and NuGet packages a pain to get, update, use & get approved if my organization can't see the source code used for the project.

Not every environment will have these restrictions-but to the pundits: don't assume you have a 1-size fits all solution. Service account passwords for database connections reside, ENCRYPTED, in things like web.config and app.config files for us-which is the angle to which I am answering this question. They cannot be domain accounts, which would allow you to do things like `Integrated Security=SSPI` or `webService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;`. Do not assume these will only be in DBs - most databases actually have their own encryption algorithms to deal with. For certain connections & environments, developer community - get over yourselves! You may actually have to supply a password and have it stored somewhere for your application to work! And guess what-NIST doesn't prohibit this, or it would not have encryption standards you can meet (which SHA512 is encouraged for) to answer this call.

So I'm going to piece together some research I did to show a couple of routes you can go for how to get this going using a key created using a SHA-512 hash, that you then encrypt/decrypt against.  You can generate a SHA-512 key either by creating a certificate or letting the RSACryptoServiceContainer give you one.

**Certificate method**

Create your certificate with these lines on a command line:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=MyCertificate" -a sha512 -b 09/01/2016 -sky exchange C:\Temp\MyCertificate.cer -sv C:\Temp\MyCertificate.pvk
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk C:\Temp\MyCertificate.pvk -pi "MyP@ssw0rd" -spc C:\Temp\MyCertificate.cer -pfx C:\Temp\MyCertificate.pfx -po "MyP@ssw0rd"
```

Then import the certificate to the local root authority store and use this code:

```
string input = "test";
string output = string.Empty;

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyCertificate", false);

X509Certificate2 certificate = collection[0];

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider cps = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key)
{
    byte[] bytesData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] bytesEncrypted = cps.Encrypt(bytesData, false);
    output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
}

store.Close();
```

**Reference**: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69e39ad0-13c2-4b5e-bb1b-972a614813fd/encrypt-with-certificate-sha512?forum=csharpgeneral

**Using RSACryptoServiceProvider to generate the keys**

```
private static string privateKey = String.Empty;

private static void generateKeys()
{
    int dwLen = 2048;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(dwLen);
    privateKey = csp.ToXmlString(true).Replace("><",">\r\n");
}

public static string Encrypt(string data2Encrypt)
{
    try
    {
        generateKeys();
        RSAx rsax = new RSAx(privateKey, 2048);
        rsax.RSAxHashAlgorithm = RSAxParameters.RSAxHashAlgorithm.SHA512;
        byte[] CT = rsax.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data2Encrypt), false, true); // first bool is for using private key (false forces to use public), 2nd is for using OAEP
        return Convert.ToBase64String(CT);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        // handle exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error during encryption: " + ex.Message);
        return String.Empty;
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string data2Decrypt)
{
    try
    {
        RSAx rsax = new RSAx(privateKey, 2048);
        rsax.RSAxHashAlgorithm = RSAxParameters.RSAxHashAlgorithm.SHA512;
        byte[] PT = rsax.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(data2Decrypt), true, true); // first bool is for using private key, 2nd is for using OAEP
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PT);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        // handle exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error during encryption: " + ex.Message);
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

These methods use a DLL called **RSAx.DLL**, built using the source code at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421656/RSA-Library-with-Private-Key-Encryption-in-Csharp , which is not mine (author: Arpan Jati), but I've used it and it is available to the developer community under [CodeProject's Open Source License](https://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx). You could also just bring in 3 classes from that project, instead:  RSAx.cs, RSAxParameters.cs, RSAxUtils.cs

The code would take this post over the 30000 char limit, so I'll just post RSAx so you can see what's going on, but all 3 classes are required.  You have to change the namespace and reference the System.Numerics assembly.

**RSAx.cs**

```
// @Date : 15th July 2012
// @Author : Arpan Jati (arpan4017@yahoo.com; arpan4017@gmail.com)
// @Library : ArpanTECH.RSAx
// @CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421656/RSA-Library-with-Private-Key-Encryption-in-Csharp  

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ArpanTECH
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main RSAx Class
    /// </summary>
    public class RSAx : IDisposable
    {
        private RSAxParameters rsaParams;
        private RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the RSA class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rsaParams">Preallocated RSAxParameters containing the required keys.</param>
        public RSAx(RSAxParameters rsaParams)
        {
            this.rsaParams = rsaParams;
            UseCRTForPublicDecryption = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the RSA class from a XML KeyInfo string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="keyInfo">XML Containing Key Information</param>
       /// <param name="ModulusSize">Length of RSA Modulus in bits.</param>
       public RSAx(String keyInfo, int ModulusSize)
       {
            this.rsaParams = RSAxUtils.GetRSAxParameters(keyInfo, ModulusSize);
            UseCRTForPublicDecryption = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hash Algorithm to be used for OAEP encoding.
        /// </summary>
        public RSAxParameters.RSAxHashAlgorithm RSAxHashAlgorithm
        {
            set
            {
                rsaParams.HashAlgorithm = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If True, and if the parameters are available, uses CRT for private key decryption. (Much Faster)
        /// </summary>
        public bool UseCRTForPublicDecryption
        {
            get;  set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Releases all the resources.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            rsaParams.Dispose();
        }

        #region PRIVATE FUNCTIONS

        /// <summary>
        /// Low level RSA Process function for use with private key.
        /// Should never be used; Because without padding RSA is vulnerable to attacks.  Use with caution.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="PlainText">Data to encrypt. Length must be less than Modulus size in octets.</param>
        /// <param name="usePrivate">True to use Private key, else Public.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted Data</returns>
        public byte[] RSAProcess(byte[] PlainText, bool usePrivate)
        {

            if (usePrivate && (!rsaParams.Has_PRIVATE_Info))
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("RSA Process: Incomplete Private Key Info");
            }

            if ((usePrivate == false) && (!rsaParams.Has_PUBLIC_Info))
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("RSA Process: Incomplete Public Key Info");
            }            

            BigInteger _E;
            if (usePrivate)
                _E = rsaParams.D; 
            else
                _E = rsaParams.E;

            BigInteger PT = RSAxUtils.OS2IP(PlainText, false);
            BigInteger M = BigInteger.ModPow(PT, _E, rsaParams.N);

            if (M.Sign == -1)
                return RSAxUtils.I2OSP(M + rsaParams.N, rsaParams.OctetsInModulus, false);            
            else
                return RSAxUtils.I2OSP(M, rsaParams.OctetsInModulus, false);                   
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Low level RSA Decryption function for use with private key. Uses CRT and is Much faster.
        /// Should never be used; Because without padding RSA is vulnerable to attacks. Use with caution.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Data">Data to encrypt. Length must be less than Modulus size in octets.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted Data</returns>
        public byte[] RSADecryptPrivateCRT(byte[] Data)
        {
            if (rsaParams.Has_PRIVATE_Info && rsaParams.HasCRTInfo)
            {
                BigInteger C = RSAxUtils.OS2IP(Data, false);

                BigInteger M1 = BigInteger.ModPow(C, rsaParams.DP, rsaParams.P);
                BigInteger M2 = BigInteger.ModPow(C, rsaParams.DQ, rsaParams.Q);
                BigInteger H = ((M1 - M2) * rsaParams.InverseQ) % rsaParams.P;
                BigInteger M = (M2 + (rsaParams.Q * H));

                if (M.Sign == -1)
                    return RSAxUtils.I2OSP(M + rsaParams.N, rsaParams.OctetsInModulus, false);
                else
                    return RSAxUtils.I2OSP(M, rsaParams.OctetsInModulus, false); 
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("RSA Decrypt CRT: Incomplete Key Info");
            }                             
        }        

        private byte[] RSAProcessEncodePKCS(byte[] Message, bool usePrivate)
        {
            if (Message.Length > rsaParams.OctetsInModulus - 11)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Message too long.");
            }
            else
            {
                // RFC3447 : Page 24. [RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCRYPT ((n, e), M)]
                // EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || Msg 

                List<byte> PCKSv15_Msg = new List<byte>();

                PCKSv15_Msg.Add(0x00);
                PCKSv15_Msg.Add(0x02);

                int PaddingLength = rsaParams.OctetsInModulus - Message.Length - 3;

                byte[] PS = new byte[PaddingLength];
                rng.GetNonZeroBytes(PS);

                PCKSv15_Msg.AddRange(PS);
                PCKSv15_Msg.Add(0x00);

                PCKSv15_Msg.AddRange(Message);

                return RSAProcess(PCKSv15_Msg.ToArray() ,  usePrivate);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Mask Generation Function
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Z">Initial pseudorandom Seed.</param>
        /// <param name="l">Length of output required.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private byte[] MGF(byte[] Z, int l)
        {
            if (l > (Math.Pow(2, 32)))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Mask too long.");
            }
            else
            {
                List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= l / rsaParams.hLen; i++)
                {
                    List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
                    data.AddRange(Z);
                    data.AddRange(RSAxUtils.I2OSP(i, 4, false));
                    result.AddRange(rsaParams.ComputeHash(data.ToArray()));
                }

                if (l <= result.Count)
                {
                    return result.GetRange(0, l).ToArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Mask Length.");
                }
            }
        }


        private byte[] RSAProcessEncodeOAEP(byte[] M, byte[] P, bool usePrivate)
        {
            //                           +----------+---------+-------+
            //                      DB = |  lHash   |    PS   |   M   |
            //                           +----------+---------+-------+
            //                                          |
            //                +----------+              V
            //                |   seed   |--> MGF ---> XOR
            //                +----------+              |
            //                      |                   |
            //             +--+     V                   |
            //             |00|    XOR <----- MGF <-----|
            //             +--+     |                   |
            //               |      |                   |
            //               V      V                   V
            //             +--+----------+----------------------------+
            //       EM =  |00|maskedSeed|          maskedDB          |
            //             +--+----------+----------------------------+

            int mLen = M.Length;
            if (mLen > rsaParams.OctetsInModulus - 2 * rsaParams.hLen - 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Message too long.");
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] PS = new byte[rsaParams.OctetsInModulus - mLen - 2 * rsaParams.hLen - 2];
                //4. pHash = Hash(P),
                byte[] pHash = rsaParams.ComputeHash(P);

                //5. DB = pHash||PS||01||M.
                List<byte> _DB = new List<byte>();
                _DB.AddRange(pHash);
                _DB.AddRange(PS);
                _DB.Add(0x01);
                _DB.AddRange(M);
                byte[] DB = _DB.ToArray();

                //6. Generate a random octet string seed of length hLen.                
                byte[] seed = new byte[rsaParams.hLen];
                rng.GetBytes(seed);

                //7. dbMask = MGF(seed, k - hLen -1).
                byte[] dbMask = MGF(seed, rsaParams.OctetsInModulus - rsaParams.hLen - 1);

                //8. maskedDB = DB XOR dbMask
                byte[] maskedDB = RSAxUtils.XOR(DB, dbMask);

                //9. seedMask = MGF(maskedDB, hLen)
                byte[] seedMask = MGF(maskedDB, rsaParams.hLen);

                //10. maskedSeed = seed XOR seedMask.
                byte[] maskedSeed = RSAxUtils.XOR(seed, seedMask);

                //11. EM = 0x00 || maskedSeed || maskedDB.
                List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
                result.Add(0x00);
                result.AddRange(maskedSeed);
                result.AddRange(maskedDB);

                return RSAProcess(result.ToArray(), usePrivate);
            }
        }


        private byte[] Decrypt(byte[] Message, byte [] Parameters, bool usePrivate, bool fOAEP)
        {
            byte[] EM = new byte[0];
            try
            {
                if ((usePrivate == true) && (UseCRTForPublicDecryption) && (rsaParams.HasCRTInfo))
                {
                    EM = RSADecryptPrivateCRT(Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    EM = RSAProcess(Message, usePrivate);
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Exception while Decryption: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception while Decryption: ");
            }

            try
            {
                if (fOAEP) //DECODE OAEP
                {
                    if ((EM.Length == rsaParams.OctetsInModulus) && (EM.Length > (2 * rsaParams.hLen + 1)))
                    {
                        byte[] maskedSeed;
                        byte[] maskedDB;
                        byte[] pHash = rsaParams.ComputeHash(Parameters);
                        if (EM[0] == 0) // RFC3447 Format : http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447
                        {
                            maskedSeed = EM.ToList().GetRange(1, rsaParams.hLen).ToArray();
                            maskedDB = EM.ToList().GetRange(1 + rsaParams.hLen, EM.Length - rsaParams.hLen - 1).ToArray();
                            byte[] seedMask = MGF(maskedDB, rsaParams.hLen);
                            byte[] seed = RSAxUtils.XOR(maskedSeed, seedMask);
                            byte[] dbMask = MGF(seed, rsaParams.OctetsInModulus - rsaParams.hLen - 1);
                            byte[] DB = RSAxUtils.XOR(maskedDB, dbMask);

                            if (DB.Length >= (rsaParams.hLen + 1))
                            {
                                byte[] _pHash = DB.ToList().GetRange(0, rsaParams.hLen).ToArray();
                                List<byte> PS_M = DB.ToList().GetRange(rsaParams.hLen, DB.Length - rsaParams.hLen);
                                int pos = PS_M.IndexOf(0x01);
                                if (pos >= 0 && (pos < PS_M.Count))
                                {
                                    List<byte> _01_M = PS_M.GetRange(pos, PS_M.Count - pos);
                                    byte[] M;
                                    if (_01_M.Count > 1)
                                    {
                                        M = _01_M.GetRange(1, _01_M.Count - 1).ToArray();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        M = new byte[0];
                                    }
                                    bool success = true;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < rsaParams.hLen; i++)
                                    {
                                         if (_pHash[i] != pHash[i])
                                        {
                                            success = false;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (success)
                                    {
                                        return M;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        M = new byte[rsaParams.OctetsInModulus]; //Hash Match Failure.
                                        throw new CryptographicException("OAEP Decode Error");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {// #3: Invalid Encoded Message Length.
                                    throw new CryptographicException("OAEP Decode Error");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {// #2: Invalid Encoded Message Length.
                                throw new CryptographicException("OAEP Decode Error");
                            }
                        }
                        else // Standard : ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/rsalabs/rsa_algorithm/rsa-oaep_spec.pdf
                        {//OAEP : THIS STADNARD IS NOT IMPLEMENTED
                            throw new CryptographicException("OAEP Decode Error");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {// #1: Invalid Encoded Message Length.
                        throw new CryptographicException("OAEP Decode Error");
                    }
                }
                else // DECODE PKCS v1.5
                {
                    if (EM.Length >= 11)
                    {
                        if ((EM[0] == 0x00) && (EM[1] == 0x02))
                        {
                            int startIndex = 2;
                            List<byte> PS = new List<byte>();
                            for (int i = startIndex; i < EM.Length; i++)
                            {
                                if (EM[i] != 0)
                                {
                                    PS.Add(EM[i]);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (PS.Count >= 8)
                            {
                                int DecodedDataIndex = startIndex + PS.Count + 1;
                                if (DecodedDataIndex < (EM.Length - 1))
                                {
                                    List<byte> DATA = new List<byte>();
                                    for (int i = DecodedDataIndex; i < EM.Length; i++)
                                    {
                                        DATA.Add(EM[i]);
                                    }
                                    return DATA.ToArray();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return new byte[0];
                                    //throw new CryptographicException("PKCS v1.5 Decode Error #4: No Data");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {// #3: Invalid Key / Invalid Random Data Length
                                throw new CryptographicException("PKCS v1.5 Decode Error");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {// #2: Invalid Key / Invalid Identifiers
                            throw new CryptographicException("PKCS v1.5 Decode Error");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {// #1: Invalid Key / PKCS Encoding
                        throw new CryptographicException("PKCS v1.5 Decode Error");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Exception while decoding: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Exception while decoding");
            }


        }

        #endregion

        #region PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts the given message with RSA, performs OAEP Encoding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">Message to Encrypt. Maximum message length is (ModulusLengthInOctets - 2 * HashLengthInOctets - 2)</param>
        /// <param name="OAEP_Params">Optional OAEP parameters. Normally Empty. But, must match the parameters while decryption.</param>
        /// <param name="usePrivate">True to use Private key for encryption. False to use Public key.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted message.</returns>
        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] Message, byte[] OAEP_Params, bool usePrivate)
        {
            return RSAProcessEncodeOAEP(Message, OAEP_Params, usePrivate);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts the given message with RSA.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">Message to Encrypt. Maximum message length is For OAEP [ModulusLengthInOctets - (2 * HashLengthInOctets) - 2] and for PKCS [ModulusLengthInOctets - 11]</param>
        /// <param name="usePrivate">True to use Private key for encryption. False to use Public key.</param>
        /// <param name="fOAEP">True to use OAEP encoding (Recommended), False to use PKCS v1.5 Padding.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted message.</returns>
        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] Message, bool usePrivate, bool fOAEP)
        {
            if (fOAEP)
            {
                return RSAProcessEncodeOAEP(Message, new byte[0], usePrivate);
            }
            else
            {
                return RSAProcessEncodePKCS(Message, usePrivate);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts the given message using RSA Public Key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">Message to Encrypt. Maximum message length is For OAEP [ModulusLengthInOctets - (2 * HashLengthInOctets) - 2] and for PKCS [ModulusLengthInOctets - 11]</param>
        /// <param name="fOAEP">True to use OAEP encoding (Recommended), False to use PKCS v1.5 Padding.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted message.</returns>
        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] Message,  bool fOAEP)
        {
            if (fOAEP)
            {
                return RSAProcessEncodeOAEP(Message, new byte[0], false);
            }
            else
            {
                return RSAProcessEncodePKCS(Message, false);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts the given RSA encrypted message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">The encrypted message.</param>
        /// <param name="usePrivate">True to use Private key for decryption. False to use Public key.</param>
        /// <param name="fOAEP">True to use OAEP.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted byte array.</returns>
        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] Message, bool usePrivate, bool fOAEP)
        {
            return Decrypt(Message, new byte[0], usePrivate, fOAEP);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts the given RSA encrypted message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">The encrypted message.</param>
        /// <param name="OAEP_Params">Parameters to the OAEP algorithm (Must match the parameter while Encryption).</param>
        /// <param name="usePrivate">True to use Private key for decryption. False to use Public key.</param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted byte array.</returns>
        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] Message, byte[] OAEP_Params, bool usePrivate)
        {
            return Decrypt(Message, OAEP_Params, usePrivate, true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts the given RSA encrypted message using Private key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">The encrypted message.</param>
        /// <param name="fOAEP">True to use OAEP.</param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted byte array.</returns>
        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] Message,  bool fOAEP)
        {
            return Decrypt(Message, new byte[0], true, fOAEP);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```