# How to define the hash size when encrypting with RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can RSACryptoServiceProvider (.NET’s RSA) use SHA256 for encryption (not signing) instead of SHA1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113498/can-rsacryptoserviceprovider-nets-rsa-use-sha256-for-encryption-not-signing)

When using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` for encryption the default hash algorithm obviously is `SHA-1`. How can I define another hash algorithm like `SHA-512` when encrypting data (using the `Encrypt` method)? I did not find any property related to the hash algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSACryptoServiceProvider will only let you set the hash function used with signing, by using one of the [SignData() overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tsc5d0z.aspx). Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's any way to change the hash used by OAEP padding without using something like the [CLRSecurity project](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/).

If you look at the [RSACng wrapper](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.RSACng&referringTitle=Security.Cryptography.dll), you can set the EncryptionHashAlgorithm property. The default looks like it's SHA256. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113498/can-rsacryptoserviceprovider-nets-rsa-use-sha256-for-encryption-not-signing) that @owelstead gave in the comments.

Comment: I think that hashing is indeed used when encrypting data with RSA. One indicator is that the maximum size of the data is calculated using the formula (modulo size - 2) - (2 * hash size in byte) when using OAEP padding. With a 1024 bit key (modulo 128) and SHA-1 hash (20 bytes) I calculate 86 byte and that's exactly what the maximum is when testing encryption using these params in a program. Another strong indicator is that the Windows Runtime allows SHA-2 and when checking the maximum size when encrypting for example with 1024 bit and SHA-256 I get 62 bytes, just as the formula results.

Comment: RSA OAEP does use a hash algo for the G and H functions. RSA PKCS v1.5 padding does not (it only pads with some static bytes and then fills the rest of it with (at least 8) random bytes.

Comment: @owlstead : Thanks for clarifying. It's not RSA that uses the hash algorithm for encryption but OAEP for padding.

Comment: Those paddings **are integral to RSA**. RSA deploys modulus exponentiation over a padded message. The RSAEP function describes how the modulus exponentiation is performed. This is sometimes (incorrectly) described as "RAW" RSA. RSAES-OAEP is one of the two RSA encryption schemes described.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking about OAEP when I answered, just PKCS v1.5. My apologies, I'll update the answer.