# How to check the signature for a signed XML document with SHA256?

Tags: .net-4.5, signing

Seems that `SignedXml.CheckSignature` is working fine only for signed documents using SHA1.

I tried [this code](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/378DF859/330F5138) by adding the algorithm SHA256, and the CheckSignature worked fine but the WIF classes started throwing the following exception:

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid algorithm specified. In this method call
System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInRequest

Seems that the ProcessSignInRequest uses the algorithm SHA1 which has been overridden internally here:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), 
                          "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
```

What did I miss? How can I specify the algorithm in CheckSignature?

Comment: Is this a specific .NET 4.5 issue? I would normally change the tag, but given your rep, I will wait for an answer. (Dammit, how did you get so many golds?)

Comment: Yes. .Net 4.5 issue only.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today. It turned out that the WIF signing certificate was generated using a CSP without SHA256 support ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11223454/280778)).

I browsed the `System.IdentityModel` source code and discovered that it contains special handling for this case. When you have the corresponding algorithm registered globally, WIF uses it instead of its internal implementation, and the `RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription` class does not include this special handling.

So I made my own `SignatureDescription` implementation which recreates the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` with default parameters, which include SHA256 support.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Represents the sha256RSA signature algorithm.
/// </summary>
public sealed class RsaPkcs1Sha256SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This type of CSP has SHA256 support
    /// </summary>
    private const int PROV_RSA_AES = 24;

    public RsaPkcs1Sha256SignatureDescription()
    {
        KeyAlgorithm = typeof(RSACryptoServiceProvider).FullName;
        DigestAlgorithm = typeof(SHA256Cng).FullName;
        FormatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter).FullName;
        DeformatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter).FullName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds support for sha256RSA XML signatures.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterForSignedXml()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(
            typeof (RsaPkcs1Sha256SignatureDescription),
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        key = GetSha2CompatibleKey(key);

        var signatureDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(key);
        signatureDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return signatureDeformatter;
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        key = GetSha2CompatibleKey(key);

        var signatureFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(key);
        signatureFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return signatureFormatter;
    }

    // Some certificates are generated without SHA2 support, this method recreates the CSP for them.
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11223454/280778
    // WIF handles this case internally if no sha256RSA support is installed globally.
    private static AsymmetricAlgorithm GetSha2CompatibleKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var csp = key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
        if (csp == null || csp.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType == PROV_RSA_AES)
            return key;

        var newKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(PROV_RSA_AES));
        newKey.ImportParameters(csp.ExportParameters(true));
        return newKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work, it is throwing a Cryptography exception `Key not valid for use in specified state.`